# I need help in javascript password validation?

Tags: javascript, validation

I am working on a password validation script.

The following code is working fine with numbers, upper- and lower-case letters.

The only problem in .press the spacebar key, length is more than 8,
display return true.

not allowed to only special characters.

```
$("#password").keyup(function () {
    var validated = true;
    if (this.value.length < 8)
        validated = false;
    if (!/\d/.test(this.value))
        validated = false;
    if (!/[a-z]/.test(this.value))
        validated = false;
    if (!/[A-Z]/.test(this.value))
        validated = false;
    if (!/[@#$%\&^\-\+=!*.?~]/.test(this.value))
        validated = false;
    if (/[^0-9a-zA-Z@#$%^&+=!*,.?~]/.test(this.value))
        validated = false;
    $('#password_strength').text(validated ? "Good" : "Too Weak");
```

Comment: You're not checking those two cases indeed...

Comment: I was only able to beautify the code. What is it that you want?

Comment: You can do all of that in a single regex. Just look at password validation libraries, it's fairly easy to find the regex.

Comment: Why shouldn't the user have spaces in their password? Note that there is a school of thought that insisting on uppercase plus lowercase plus numbers and punctuation makes passwords _less_ secure because it forces users to write them down to remember them. Note also that validating on keyup isn't enough, because the user may paste text in via the edit menu...

Comment: `/[^0-9a-zA-Z@#$%^&+=!*,.?~]/.test(this.value))` - this part is the most stupid you could think of - **NEVER** limit what chars user wants to use in their password

Comment: @Steven: and you do write all your code in one line. We (well, most of us) write code for people, so it should be at first readable. The code from the question is readable and maintainable.

Comment: huh? A single regex can handle all of those cases he wants. He doesn't need 6 if statements. If you can't read a regex that's not my problem. That code is no more "readable" and "maintainable" then having a single if with a slightly longer regex.

Comment: @Steven: could you be so kind to provide a single regex that does **all** of that. Seems like it's pretty easy for you, isn't it? I'm really curious how longer it could be, and how less readable. PS: I know how to do that in 1 regex, and I don't see how it can be a maintainable one.

Answer (score 0):

When checking for symbols in your password using regex, you'll want to escape them so they're taken as the literal character, not the regex meaning of the character. For more information, I would recommend checking out:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: What did you want to express? "When checking for symbols in your password using regex, you'll want to escape them so they're taken as the literal character, not the regex meaning of the character." --- elaborate this.

Comment: For instance, the character `.` in regex is a placeholder for _any character_ other than whitespace. Where as `\.`is just the period symbol.

Comment: in `[]` it doesn't behave like that. So `[.]` is a set that includes a point character.